# profiler output in file format

Tags: profiling, profiler

Is there any profiler which which generates an output in any file format?

I need to open a profiler output on multiple machines and I wish to parse the output myself as a side project.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: As I said in the question I wish to open output of the profiler on multiple computers and I wish to parse the output to analyze it later. I tried many profilers and search online for any profilers that might help. But I could not find any so I turned to stack overflow as a last option.